# Single Sign on / SharePoint 2010

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, security-token-service

We currently have a SP2010 farm, with a number of web applications all configured to used classic windows authentication. One of our service providers has an externally hosted application that we want to launch from our SharePoint 2010 portal and not have the user to login again. So I'm looking to implement SSO. The service provider has a SAML enabled login page that is expecting SAML tokens (the encrypted value is passed to a hidden input on the form).

What I need to know, is how can I generate these SAML tokens from SharePoint 2010? I also believe I will need some form of mapping, which links our AD users credentials to their credentials on the external system?

I appreciate this question is probably constantly asked, but the information out there is a little overwhelming and I'm looking for the most simple solution.

If anyone needs any more details please let me know and I'll furnish if I can.

Comment: I know what I'm about to say isn't constructive, but this is one of the reasons it makes sense to follow Microsoft recommendation of creating all new web applications with claims authentication instead of classic. You could try recreating the web application with claims and migrating the content. Alternatively, use the SecureStore Service Application for mapping users in SharePoint to users in your external application and providing the SAML connection.

Comment: Just a note: there is no (valid) recommendation on creating all new web applications using claims. Seriously consider this and now the limitations of claims enabled web apps when you're creating new web apps.

Comment: Hi All, to be honest I've discovered this is out of the realm of SharePoint, we just needed something generating SAML tokens with 2 attributes in the assertions, it was easier to code something up using this  http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SAMLv20.aspx. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Shaneo if this solved your problem, please post it as answer to your own question

Comment: @Shaneo - you just need to paste this as your answer and click on "Post Your Answer". You can do this yourself - no need to flag for the moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be honest I've discovered this is out of the realm of SharePoint, we just needed something generating SAML tokens with 2 attributes in the assertions, it was easier to code something up using this componentspace.com/Products/SAMLv20.aspx. Thanks everyone for your help.